# VueJS3 + Typescript - Read file from input file

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to upload some file, but I can't access with `v-model`

> VueCompilerError: v-model cannot be used on file inputs since they are read-only. Use a v-on:change listener instead.

So, I've change the `v-model` to `v-on:change` like code below, but I don't know how to do this

```
<input
  type="file"
  name="file"
  v-on:change="uploadFile"
  style="display: none; border: none"
/>
```

I read a big list of examples, but none worked.

My data *(Idk if it's right)*:

```
data() {
  return {
    file: null as unknown as File,
  };
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic example could look like this

```html
<input type="file" @change="onFileChange">
```

JavaScript version

```js
methods: {
  onFileChange(e) {
    let files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
    if (!files.length) 
      return;

    doSomethingWithTheFile(files[0]);
  },
}
```

TypeScript version could look like this

```
interface HTMLInputEvent extends Event {
  target: HTMLInputElement & EventTarget
}


methods: {
  onFileChange(event: HTMLInputEvent | DragEvent) {
    let files =
      (event as HTMLInputEvent).target.files ||
      (event as DragEvent).dataTransfer.files
    if (!files.length) return

    doSomethingWithTheFile(files[0])
  },
},
```

Comment: typescript return a lot of error because Idk who is `e` and `files`? what is the `file` type is `File`?

Comment: I have added a TypeScript version @ThiagoValente

Comment: HTMLInputEvent doesn't seem to exist. I have tsconfig.json -> compilerOptions -> lib : [ "dom" ... ] set and it fails to compile.

Answer (score 3):

What does your `uploadFile` look like?

The simpler may be to declare it to take directly the files list:

```
async uploadFiles(fileList: Array<File>) {
    for (const file of fileList) {
        // do something with the file
```

And call it this way:

```
v-on:change="uploadFiles($event.target.files)"
```

Answer (score 0):

For vue3js we would get the following typescript setup:

```
<script setup lang="ts">  
interface HTMLInputEvent extends Event {
  target: HTMLInputElement & EventTarget;
}

const fileChanged = (ev: HTMLInputEvent | DragEvent) => {
  let files = (ev as HTMLInputEvent).target.files || (ev as DragEvent).dataTransfer?.files;
  if (!files?.length) return;

  doSomethingWithTheFile(files[0]);
};
</script>
```